# Access reference to class inside its own class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

In the code below, how can I access the variable `User` **without explicitly specifying the keyword "User"** inside its own class?

```js
class User {
  say = () => {
    // Here, I have to explicitly write "User". Is there
    // some javascript trick to get the class reference inside 
    // its own class without explicitly writing the name?
    console.log(User);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a standard function instead of an arrow function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you show an example?

Comment: Once you have a standard function, just refer to `this.constructor`

Comment: @CertainPerformance how do i do it in an es6 class?

Comment: `class User {
  say() {
    console.log(this.constructor);
  }
}`

Comment: would `say = () => { console.log(this.constructor); }` also work @andrew